# How do you make bangs with hair dynamics?

Tags: animation, particles, physics, eevee-render-engine, hair

I gave up on just trying to add hair physics to an already made hair mesh, so I decided to finally look at the hair dynamics that's been haunting me the past few months.

I was really impressed when I saw a tutorial on it, and now I want to try, but I only have 2 quick questions.

1. How do you make bangs with hair dynamics? I saw someone do it with bangs but you have to pay for a tutorial... it's probably just like fixing the hair strands a little bit but if there's an easier way can anyone let me know? And ...
2. Is it possible to have multiple hair dynamics on one mesh? These questions are kind of dumb, considering they probably have easy answers, but I guess I'm just looking for a confirmation. I think you'd have to just apply more strands on the mesh, correct? 
    And if it is, is there a way to get it to move separately from a different one?
   For example, say you wanna have long hair at the back and then two side braided ponytails. You'd do the back first and then create more strands to make the ponytails, right? But what if you accidentally move the back hair?

So there's that, I'm sorry these are so simple but this is my first time ever looking into hair dynamics. ✨

Comment: About 1.) can you give an example of what you're looking for? Bangs at the forehead or at the sides? What's the problem related to Hair Dynamics? About 2.) Yes, you can have more than one Hair Particle System and each particle system has its own settings. With the help of the *Density* group, you can specify where the hair should be.

Comment: @Blunder Forehead bangs.

Comment: What's the problem related to Hair Dynamics?